# Simulations between Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, simulation

I've got a question. How can i simulate Turing machine with a double-sided infinite tape by a Turing machine with one-sided infinite tape? The condition is, that the simulation of one step of the first machine must be equal to `O(1)` steps of second machine. Do you have any idea, how to do this?

Comment: do you have more description about what a dopple sided tape is? what properties does it have and how does it work?

Comment: I believe that you can find the transformation you look for in this document : http://staff.um.edu.mt/afra1/teaching/coco4.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, the double-sided machine has a tape indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$ and the one-sided has a tape indexed by $\mathbb{N}$.

The question then boils down to finding a bijection f between the two sets st. $\forall z \in \mathbb{Z}: |f(z) - f(z+1)| < k$ for some constant k. Can you find such a bijection:

Hint: k = 3 is sufficient.